# Guarantee that certain messages will not be serialized

Tags: akka, akka.net

Suppose, in a certain state, an akka actor A creates a child actor B:

`Context.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new BActor(RawDetails)));`

`RawDetails` is a fairly large but simple object without references that must be transformed in the actual data object `SmartDetails` which contains many references.

`SmartDetails` is created in the constructor of `BActor` and must now be sent to akka actor A.

I must have the guarantee that `SmartDetails` will not be serialized when sending it from B to A.

Is this a valid way to proceed in akka?
We tested it and it works, i.e. it is not serialized.

I am searching for documentation where e.g. I can find a statement that a child actor is created in the same process as the parent actor and that serialization will not take place.

When message `SmartDetails` is serialized akka will crash because `SmartDetails` is too big.

The original `RawDetails` came from another actor in serialized form, and it was "shipped" in small simple packets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default messages within the same `ActorSystem` (same process and AppDomain) are not serialized - hence why it's so important they be immutable.

The documentation mentions it [here](http://getakka.net/articles/networking/serialization.html), under the "Verification" section:

> Normally, messages sent between local actors (i.e. same CLR) do not
>   undergo serialization. For testing, sometimes, it may be desirable to
>   force serialization on all messages (both remote and local).

**But messages sent to another actor system via remoting/clustering will be serialized.**

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I couldn't find myself.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!